# how to point to delimiter at fixed position in std::string

Tags: c++, string, find, std

Say I have text say with '#' as a delimiter.
example

```
 std::string key = "012#txt1#txt2#txt3#txt4#  #some other text:"
```

I have to insert modified text between #at position 5 and #at position 6.     The one shown above with spaces in between.

To accomplish this I need to find 5th # and 6th #. 
I wrote a small code but its not doing what i expect to do.It always return first found '#'. can someone please advice me.

```
std::string temp = key;
 size_t found = 0;

  size_t pos_key = temp.find('#');
  while( ( found !=5 )&& ( pos_key != std::string::npos )  )
    {
        found++;
        temp.find_first_of('#', pos_key + 1 );
        temp.erase(0, pos_key );
    }
  std::cout << " the pos key is " << pos_key << std::endl ;
```

Comment: sorry , I just modified my text here while positing it

Comment: why don't you just split the string and find the desired element?

Comment: That code doesn't just find the position, it deletes everything up to what it finds along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems going on.  first you never update `pos_key` so you are stomping all over your string when you call `erase` which I am not sure why you are doing that.  If you need to find the nth symbol you can use a function like:

```
size_t find_nth(const std::string & line, const std::string & symbol, size_t nth)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    size_t counter = 0;
    while (counter < nth && (pos = line.find(symbol, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        counter++; // found a match so increment
        pos++;  // increment so we search for the next one
    }
    return pos;
}
```

And you can see it running in this <kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb66328259b7fe8b)</kbd>

Comment: @Galik You are totally correct.  I have removed it from here and the live example.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have two problems.

First you are not remembering the position of the '#' when you find it, you need to assign the return value of the `std::string::find_first_of` function to `pos_key`.

Second you keep deleting the contents of the string up to the position you find. That throws off all the position information you got from the `std::string::find_first_of` function.

I think  this might be what you need:

```
int main()
{
    std::string key = "012#txt1#txt2#txt3#txt4#  #some other text:";

    std::string temp = key;
    size_t found = 0;

    size_t pos_key = temp.find('#');
    while((found != 5) && (pos_key != std::string::npos))
    {
        found++;
        // this line does nothing with the found position
        // temp.find_first_of('#', pos_key + 1);

        // instead record the position of the latest '#'
        pos_key = temp.find_first_of('#', pos_key + 1);

        // this line just deletes most of the string
        // for no apparent reason
        // temp.erase(0, pos_key);
    }
    std::cout << " the pos key is " << pos_key << std::endl;
}
```